# how to build exe of my project on visual studio using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssms

My project is complete now I want to make it live for testing. how to make it executable for people?
I want to make it exe

Comment: You would have to publish the project.  Go to build -> publish after you've configured the publish settings. A /publish folder should open up Immediately after that is complete.

Comment: @Sarim, Did the answer help clarify your question. If yes please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This will also help others understand you've found a solution

Answer (score 2):

Project -> Build, then you could see in the project folder 'Bin' where will be your exe file

Comment: It would probably be helpful to point out the difference between Debug and Release builds.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can go to

> Project > Build > Build Solution
>
> In Solution Explorer > Right Click On Your Project > Open Project
>   Folder

Navigate to

Bin \ Debug or Bin \ Release this is where you will find the assemblies of your compiled project

Additionally:

In VS you can set project properties to do Release Build, which will perform some optimization and remove .PDB files in the output

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2019